# Xamarin.Auth AccountStore not deleting values?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Whenever I call my method which removes something from the AccountStore in Xamarin, it deletes it and says that there is one less thing in that list. The method below is called first from the dependency service.

```
public void DeleteSecureValue(string appName, string key)
{
    var account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(appName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (account.Properties.ContainsKey(key))
        account.Properties.Remove(key);

    var props = account.Properties;
    // when debugging, props doesn't contain a value for passcode
}
```

---

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IStorageHandler>().DeleteSecureValue(GlobalConstants.APP_NAME, "passcode");

var account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(GlobalConstants.APP_NAME).FirstOrDefault();
var props = account.Properties;
// when debugging, props now has a value for passcode when it shouldn't
```

Why does the value for passcode seem to come back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just manipulating a Dictionary in memory in `DeleteSecureValue`. You have to write your changes back to your storage.

```
public void DeleteSecureValue(string appName, string key)
{
    var store = AccountStore.Create();
    var account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(appName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (account.Properties.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        account.Properties.Remove(key);
        store.Save(account, appName);
    }
}
```